# how to display images and videos in a site from a database in php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to display videos from my database called K-Movies in a table called videos. 
But I don't know how.
Can someone help. THANKS!

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: Its a big file but does not work. I want my page to get the images from the database and display them in div tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here you go assuming you have your image src stored in a your database

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","K-Movies");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from videos")) {
while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<img src='". $fetch['image'] ."' />";
}
} else {
echo "Query failed";
}
```

Comment: What if the files are many? I want it to look like: dayt.se you can check that site

Comment: you need to fetch other data like name and rating and year etc.. and display them on hover by css (easy misison) and you need to organize them, using bootstrap will be very quick and helpful